# React-popup no preventing scrolling

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using [react-popup](https://react-popup.elazizi.com/) to show a popup and prevent clicking and scrolling outside of the popup. The popup is generated by:

```js
<Popup 
    modal 
    on = "focus"
    role="dialog"
    open = {open}
    closeOnDocumentClick = {false} 
    lockScroll = {true}
    onClose={closeModal}
    overlayStyle = {{ background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)' }}
>
    <div className='max-w-[500px] w-[90vw]  bg-white p-[20px]'>
        <h3 className='text-center text-xl font-bold m-5'>This content is free but you must subscribe to keep reading</h3>
        
        <div className='px-[30px]'>
            <SubscribeForm hasSubscribed = {hasSubscribed} setHasSubscribed = {setHasSubscribed}/>
        </div>
    </div>
</Popup>
```

it seems that when the popup opens, `overflow: auto;` is added to the document.body.styles. I have tried manually overwriting the overflow using `document.body.style.overflow = 'unset';` and `document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'`, but the  overflow changes momentarily then reverts back to auto.

Not sure how to override this behavior, any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **useEffect**

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    }
    return () => {
        document.body.style.overflow = 'unset';
    };
}, [open]);
```